# Using an outer scope variable inside a future is blocking future in scala3

Tags: multithreading, scala, future

Using a slightly modified sample code from [cookbook](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/future-example-scala-cookbook-oncomplete-callback/):

```
val sleeptime = 1000
```

I replaced the hardset constant with a val.

Using 2.13.8, the program executes as expected

```
$ scala FuturesExample3
1 - starting calculation ...
2- before onComplete
A ...
B ...
Got the callback, meaning = 42
C ...
D ...
E ...
F ...
```

But if compiled and executed in scala 3.1.2:

```
$  scala FuturesExample3
1 - starting calculation ...
2- before onComplete
A ...
B ...
C ...
D ...
E ...
F ...
```

The result is significantly different. In scala 3.1.2 (looking at the generated jstack), the new thread is object.wait() on sleeptime.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object FuturesExample3 extends App {
  val sleeptime = 1000

  println("1 - starting calculation ...")
  val f = Future {
    sleep(sleeptime*2)
    42
  }

  println("2- before onComplete")
  f.onComplete {
    case Success(value) => println(s"Got the callback, meaning = $value")
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
  }

  // do the rest of your work
  println("A ..."); sleep(sleeptime)
  println("B ..."); sleep(sleeptime)
  println("C ..."); sleep(sleeptime)
  println("D ..."); sleep(sleeptime)
  println("E ..."); sleep(sleeptime)
  println("F ..."); sleep(sleeptime)

  def sleep(duration: Long): Unit = { Thread.sleep(duration) }

}
```

Can you please help me answer two questions:

1. Why is scala3 generating byte code that is blocking on reading an outer scope val?
2. More importantly, this highlights the difficulty of upgrading from scala 2.x to 3.x because scala3's behavior, at least to me, is not intuitive.

Comment: Don't use `App` use a proper `main` method, I am pretty sure that will fix the problem.

Comment: `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {...` did fix it! I'm curious why but now it's much less urgent since `extends App` is generally used for prototyping not production code. Thanks Luis

Answer (score 0):

With the correct Scala 3 style main method it doesn't compile:

```
sleep is a forward reference extending over the definition of f
```